# How can I get annotation data from YT API

Tags: youtube-api

I've searched the docs and can't figure out how to get annotations on my videos via API.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't think that's possible at this point. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/YpIWAJfrgAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations are not accessible via API right now, but there is a work going on to enable this soon.