# Programmatic annotations via YouTube's Data API

Tags: java, python, youtube, youtube-api

Wondering if anyone knows of a way to insert annotations programmatically using YouTube's Data API. It's entirely possible to access functions like upload, meta-data, etc. I don't see anything annotations however.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Basically I'm trying to upload a video that has a different annotation on every frame (that points to a corresponding frame elsewhere in the video) — obviously the GUI YouTube provides would make that incredibly time consuming.

Here's an real example of the sort of functionality I'm after:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNRMSKSZY04

Any ideas welcome so long as they sit natively within the YouTube environment.

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get annotation data from YT API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221531/how-can-i-get-annotation-data-from-yt-api)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Annotating YouTube videos programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175/annotating-youtube-videos-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not do it using the API. One way would be a browser Plugin to do this using the annotations-page...